# Closed orbits of complete flags in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, bilinear-form

Let $B$ be a symmetric (or antisymmetric) non-degenerate bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $G$ be the associated group of automorphisms $O(n)$ (resp. $Sp(n)$). What can we say about the Zariski-closed $G$-orbits on the variety of complete flags in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for these two cases?